# changing directory permissions recursively before deleting with Python

Tags: python

```
    print "Deleting ", temp_dir
    try:
        os.chmod(temp_dir, stat.S_IRWXU)
        shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
    except Exception, e:
        print(e)
        raise
```

throws error "[Error 5] Access is denied: 'c:\temp\metabuild\common\build\build.cmd' "

owner has only read permission on file build.cmd, I added chmod line as shown in the code to change it, but it didn't do anything, permissions are still same, any help? thanks.

Comment: First, are you sure the exception isn't coming from the `os.chmod` call? Printing just the exception rather than the whole traceback, and putting multiple statements that could all raise into the same `try` block, makes it hard to tell the difference…

Comment: Second, do you have write access to the `c:\temp\metabuild\common\build\` parent directory?

Comment: 1. yes, I am sure it's coming from rmtree command, if I remove the rmtree line and execute the script, it doesn't throw this error, but still didn't change permissions.

Comment: 2. yes, I have access to c:\temp\metabuild\common\build

Comment: OK, when you say "permissions are same", _what_ are the permissions that you see (and how are you looking at them)?

Comment: with ls -l, I have cygwin in my pc. "build" dir has drwxr-xr-x and build\build.cmd has -r--r--r--

Comment: OK, Windows doesn't actually have POSIX permissions like that; it has ACLs, which are much more complicated. Cygwin tries to simulate POSIX permissions on top of the ACLs that Windows is actually using, but there are many cases that just can't be expressed in POSIX terms, so things won't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, there are a wide range of reasons you may not be able to delete a file or directory even though `os.stat` says you have write access to it:

- You may not have write access to the parent directory.
- The filesystem may be read-only.
- The file may be currently open in some other process which didn't use the [`FILE_SHARE_DELETE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) sharing mode (which most programs don't—in particular, any program using the POSIX-style APIs that Python uses for files will never use this sharing mode).
- The actual ACLs on the file may be too complex to be represented as POSIX-style permissions, so you don't actually have permission to delete the file even though both it and its parent directly show up as +w in Unix-style functions like `stat`.

Unless it's the first one, there's really no way to figure out exactly what's going on via the POSIX-y APIs that Python uses; it doesn't understand Windows sharing modes, ACLs, or anything else that could be a problem. You will need to use tools that work via the native Win32 APIs. You can do this from Python via [`pywin32`](http://pywin32.sourceforge.net) (or `ctypes` or similar to the DLLs, if you really prefer), but you probably want to figure out the problem with Explorer or the various [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals) tools first.

If you don't know all the crazy ways in which Win32 is not like POSIX, read [Creating and Opening Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN.

Also, if you're running this code under a Cygwin Python rather than a native Python, you will have to switch; inside Cygwin, you can only access the Cygwin layer, which emulates a real POSIX environment on top of Windows, and doesn't give you access to the Win32 stuff underneath.

Anyway, once you know what the problem is, most likely the only way to work around it in your code will be to again drop to the Win32 APIs via `pywin32`. Or, if you're trying to do something like override sharing modes, you have to drop even lower, to the NT layer, which you'll have to access via `ctypes`. And since most of the stuff you need isn't really documented (for the parts that *are* documented, search for "driver development") you'll probably have to dig through the C source to the Sysinternals tools to figure out how to force another process to close a file, or delete the file even though the other process has it closed.